Interaction of the spin connection with photon
When studying fermions in curved spacetime, a spin connection field $\omega_{\mu}^{ab}$ is introduced as a result of Lorentz invariance. How would this spin connection field $\omega_{\mu}^{ab}$ interact with photon?

I'm pretty sure the spin connection doesn't, but the tetrad/vielbein does. If I recall correctly, the Dirac equation in curved spacetime is $(ie^\mu_a \gamma^a D_\mu - m)\psi = 0$, and the new covariant derivative $D_\mu$ should look like $D_\mu = \nabla_\mu + i e Q A_\mu$, with $Q$ the particle's charge. $\nabla_\mu$ is the term with the spin connection, if I'm not mistaken, so it does not interact with the photon. Been a long time since I dealt with fermions, though, so double check everything
